# nodejs-slackbot - downloaded file is corrupted

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

i have created a slackbot with nodejs using `@slack/bolt`.
i'm able to receive event in my nodejs server from slack whenever i tag with my slackapp and send textMessage or textMessage+Fileattachment. Please find the nodejs source code and output of the event object below.

The problem is, when i upload a file in slack, the event is received by my nodejs `slack-bot`. (shown in below screenshot+view the event object details in the output attached below)

- The links to the uploaded file is retrieved by the nodejs slack-bot from the event object
- i'm able to use the link in web browser(for eg. google chrome) to view the uploaded file.
- When i use the link to download the file via nodejs code, the file gets downloaded, but the downloaded file is corrupted

i'm not sure how to download the valid file using nodejs slack-bot. i have tried changing few parameters and settings but no success. The docs aren't helping me so far

Please help me out

[image]

> **Nodejs source code**

```
const { App : BoltApp } = require('@slack/bolt');
const boltAppObj = new BoltApp({
    token: constants.BOT_TOKEN, 
    appToken: constants.SLACK_APP_TOKEN,
    socketMode: true,
    scopes:["files:read","files:write"]
});
  
(async () => {
    await boltAppObj.start();
    console.log('⚡️ Bolt app started');


    boltAppObj.event('app_mention', async ({ event, context, client, say }) => {
        console.log("in app_mention")
        console.log("event ",event)
        try {
          await say({"blocks": [
            {
              "type": "section",
              "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": `Thanks for the mention <@${event.user}>!`
              } 
            }
          ]});
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
})();
```

> **Output**

```
event  {
  type: 'app_mention',
  text: '<@U01NJR8JNDQ> good morning have a nice day',
  files: [
    {
      id: 'F01P0V0SC9X',
      created: 1613713912,
      timestamp: 1613713912,
      name: 'hiddencloudvillage.png',
      title: 'hiddencloudvillage.png',
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      filetype: 'png',
      pretty_type: 'PNG',
      user: 'U01NJPG7RGS',
      editable: false,
      size: 18207,
      mode: 'hosted',
      is_external: false,
      external_type: '',
      is_public: true,
      public_url_shared: false,
      display_as_bot: false,
      username: '',
      url_private: 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X/hiddencloudvillage.png',
      url_private_download: 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X/download/hiddencloudvillage.png',
      thumb_64: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X-9f0babf31c/hiddencloudvillage_64.png',
      thumb_80: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X-9f0babf31c/hiddencloudvillage_80.png',
      thumb_360: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X-9f0babf31c/hiddencloudvillage_360.png',
      thumb_360_w: 360,
      thumb_360_h: 360,
      thumb_480: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X-9f0babf31c/hiddencloudvillage_480.png',
      thumb_480_w: 480,
      thumb_480_h: 480,
      thumb_160: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X-9f0babf31c/hiddencloudvillage_160.png',
      original_w: 640,
      original_h: 640,
      thumb_tiny: 'AwAwADDToqtPfRRP5YDO/ooqP+0VU/vIZUHqRQBdoqCW7iiiV87g33Qveof7Q/6d5fyoAu0VS/tD/p3l/KpIL2OaTyyrI/YMOtAEb208U7y2zr85yysKRkvplKOYkU8HHNXqz9r3lzMplZEjOAq0AJLbtatbvGpkWPII7/Wp/t8X2fzcN97btxzmmf2ee1zN+dO+wR/Z/K3Nndu3d80AN/tFf+eEv5UwM95dROsTIkZyWYdafZvItxLbvIZAnIY9au0AFVprJJZPMVmjc9Sp61ZooApf2ef+fmb86P7PP/PzN+dXaKAIbe2S3UhMknqx6mpqKKAP/9k=',
      permalink: 'https://pov-vtapbot.slack.com/files/U01NJPG7RGS/F01P0V0SC9X/hiddencloudvillage.png',
      permalink_public: 'https://slack-files.com/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01P0V0SC9X-df55a3dc04',
      is_starred: false,
      has_rich_preview: false
    }
  ],
  upload: false,
  blocks: [ { type: 'rich_text', block_id: 'ZecUF', elements: [Array] } ],
  user: 'U01NJPG7RGS',
  display_as_bot: false,
  ts: '1613713934.000900',
  channel: 'C01NXCJ2EN5',
  event_ts: '1613713934.000900'
}
```

> **Script to download file using the url available in events object**

```
const axios=require("axios");
const fs = require("fs")
const constants = require("./constants");

let url="https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T01NC0NH1KQ-F01N7CHRGF9/download/poc.xlsx";
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${constants.SLACK_APP_TOKEN}` }
};
axios({
    method: "GET",
    url  : url,
    responseType: "stream",
    headers : config.headers
}).then((result)=>{
    console.log("result ")
    result.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./poc.xlsx"));

}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("err ");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The issue was due to the type of token passed to the file download api
- `BOT_TOKEN` is the appropriate token that has to be passed to the file download api
- Issue got fixed once i passed the `BOT_TOKEN` to the file download api

**Below is the logic to download the file that was uploaded in slack**

```
const downloadFile= (url,filename)=>{

    let fullFilePath = "";
    const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${constants.BOT_TOKEN}` }
        };
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url  : url,
            responseType: "stream",
            headers : config.headers
        }).then((result)=>{
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fullFilePath);
            result.data.on('data', (chunk) => {
                writeStream.write(chunk);
            });
            result.data.on('end', function () {
                writeStream.uncork();
                writeStream.close();
                writeStream.end();
                console.log("completely ending the pipe");
            });
            writeStream.on('finish', () => {
                resolve(fullFilePath);
            });
            // This is here incase any errors occur
            writeStream.on('error', function (err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        }).catch((err)=>{
            reject(err);
        });
    });
    return promise;
};
```

**Below is the sample logic for nodejs-slackbot integration**

```
const constants = require("./constants");
const { App : BoltApp } = require('@slack/bolt');
const utility = require("./utility");
const path = require("path");

const BOT_PORT = 3000;
const boltAppObj = new BoltApp({
    token: constants.BOT_TOKEN, 
    signingSecret : constants.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
});
  
const sendMessageToSlack= async (event,say,chatmessage)=>{
    await say({
        text: `Hey there <@${event.user}>! , ${chatmessage}`
      });
}

(async () => {
    await boltAppObj.start(BOT_PORT);
    console.log('⚡️ Bolt app started');

    boltAppObj.event('app_mention', async ({ event, context, client, say }) => {
        const textMessage = event.text;
        try{
            const filePath = await utility.getLocalFilePath(event.files ? event.files : null);
            sendMessageToSlack(event,say,"success");
        }
        catch(err){
            sendMessageToSlack(event,say,"failed");
        }
    })

})();
```

**Feel free to contact me if you are facing any issue related to this topic**

**Response to comment made by @ppp**

Please verify if `files:read` permission is present in the slackbot application which you have created on slack website

[image]

Comment: I assume `BOT_TOKEN` refers to the token string beginning with `xoxb-` (the bot user OAuth token)?

I am trying your code with that but I can't for the life of me download the file without ending up being corrupted locally.

And just like you - I retrieve the link to the uploaded file from the event object, I'm able to use the link in Chrome to view (and download) the uploaded file, and the file will download via Node but the downloaded file is corrupted.

Comment: please look into my updated answer and let me know if it helps @ppp

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer with a screenshot. I can confirm `files:read` bot token scope is there.

I also managed to download the file successfully with my token through `curl` - so I know the token has the right scope. At this point, only Node gives me a corrupted download.

Comment: @ppp are you using the link present in `url_private_download` for downloading file via nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was getting a broken image even after providing `user:read` permission to Bot token scopes. The reason is because, the my bot was not added to the channel where the file was added.

I had used user token `xoxp-xxxx` to fetch the files the user has access to. To download the file, I added `files:read` to User Token Scopes and used the user token to download the file and it worked like a charm.